# Background zoom in animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying zoom in animation for background image for a particular second. it's happening but it resets again.

i created sample link in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/onlinesolution/tk6rcLdx/

what am i missing here?

```
body:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://paulmason.name/media/demos/full-screen-background-image/background.jpg");
    background-position:center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     z-index: -9;
    -webkit-animation: zoomin 5s ease-in;
    animation: zoomin 5s ease-in;
        }

/* Zoom in Keyframes */
@-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
  0% {transform: scale(1);}
  100% {transform: scale(1.5);}
}
@keyframes zoomin {
  0% {transform: scale(1);}
  100% {transform: scale(1.5);}
} /*End of Zoom in Keyframes */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a simple propertie: `animation-fill-mode: forwards`

Here's your code with that propertie added, you will see that works fine

https://codepen.io/manAbl/pen/vjbgYK

Further reading:

https://devdocs.io/css/animation-fill-mode

Comment: In edge browser image some thing flickering(jumbing) any idea how to solve this issue, now only i noticed in edge browser 
Thanks